# Homology of $H_1(X_m)$.

Tags: homological-algebra

Let $X_m$ be a space obtained from $S^1$ by attaching $D^2$ through the map $f(z)=z^m$ around the boundary.  I have computed the homology group of it by exact sequence

$$\mathbb{Z} \cong H_1(S^1)\xrightarrow{\times m} H_1(X_m) \rightarrow H_1(X_m,S^1)\cong \widetilde{H}_1(X_m/S^1)\cong H_1(X_m/S^1)\cong H_1(S^2)\cong 0.  $$

In particular,
$$\mathbb{Z}\xrightarrow{\times m} H_1(X_m) \rightarrow 0$$

Thus, the first map is surjective so $H_1(X_m)\cong m\mathbb{Z}$.

Am I correct?

Comment: Does $m=3{{}}$?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown It should have been arbitrary integer $m$. I have corrected !  Thanks!

Comment: When you say $m\Bbb Z$, do you mean the subgroup of $\Bbb Z$ generated by $m$?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Yes, I mean $m\mathbb{Z}=\left< m \right>$ not $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$. :)

Comment: So then $m\Bbb Z\cong\Bbb Z$ so you are saying $H_1(X_m)\cong\Bbb Z$?

Comment: What does $\times m$ mean for a map between two abstract groups ? Perhaps you should look further in the long exact sequence and see that the term on the left of what you wrote also happens to be a $\mathbb Z$

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown  I think so!  But then my question is if $H_1(X_m)\cong \mathbb{Z}$...

Comment: Is that true for $m=1$? @LevBan

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Ah... then it is wrong... Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One can represent $X_m$ as a CW-complex with one $0$-cell, one $1$-cell and one $2$-cell. One gets a cellular chain complex
$$0\to C_2\to C_1\to C_0\to0$$
where each $C_i\cong\Bbb Z$. The differential $C_1\to C_0$ is zero, so its kernel
is $C_1$. The differential $C_2\to C_1$ takes a generator of $C_2$
to $m$ times a generator of $C_1$. Then $H_1(X_m)$ is the homology of this
complex at the middle term, which is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z/m\Bbb Z$.

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer  :) Could I ask why the differential $C_1\rightarrow C_0$ is zero?  If it is true, then shouldn't kernel is $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: I got it! Thanks!